A movie most likely related to Yoni Natanyahu
I watched the movie about 10 years ago when I was a kid. It's about a special troop secretly flying a long way to the enemy's airport to rescue the hostages imprisoned there. 10 years later, I learnt this plot is very similar to Operation Entebbe in Uganda in 1976. The special troop is the elite Israeli army commando unit Sayeret Matkal. And Yoni Natanyahu was the commander of it and died in that mission. He is also the elder brother of the current Prime Minister of Israel, Benjamin Netanyahu. So what is the name of that movie? Note it is not the documentary, Follow me: The Yoni Natanyahu Story.

What's the country\language? How old would you say this movie is (assuming you saw it on TV)? Do you remember anything else about it (specific scenes or characters)? Any details might help, however minor.

Honestly speaking, memory doesn't serve well since it's been long time. I am inclined to believe it's a movie in English from the U.S. It's at least 10 years old. The only scene I can recall clearly is a significant character in the movie was killed at the time he grabs the handle of the entrance of the running rescuing aircraft. I suspect this character is originated from Yoni Natanyahu.

could be http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076594/ or http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075391/ or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFeDt0eVcTE

I somehow got the impression azheanda wanted a movie with a plot similar to these events or inspired by them, not a film that depicts them directly. (In which case Delta Force might fit, but I don't think it features the scene described in the comments.)

@dav1dsm1th It's the first one! Thanks!

@azheanda - you cam merk dav1dsm1ths answer correct by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Apparently I stumbled on the answer, Raid on Entebbe - (1976), doing a google search for Entebbe related movies.
